# Get Key from nested dictionarites in JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I want to get Key from dictionary. and my dictionary is

```
JsonDict{
       1{
          name:"sam"
          value:"1000"
        }
       2{
          name:"harry"
          value:"2000"
        }
       3{
          name:"potter"
          value:"3000"
        }
    }
```

If JsonDict is an NSArray then i knew how to get it from for loop But its a Dictionary.

my question is how to get name from this json ?

My Code is...

//----From this i am getting Json------

```
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [responseString JSONValue];

NSArray *array= (NSArray *)[jsonObject allKeys];


for (int i =0; i<[array count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictLocation = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    //NSLog(@"Index :%@",dictLocation);
    NSDictionary *dictName12 = [dictLocation objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog(@"%i : %@",i,dictName12);


}
```

i am getting dictLocation in above code but not dictName12...

Comment: i have tried "for loop". for that loop i took jsonDict as array like this (array*). and i got every dictionaries in jsonDict. means 1,2,3. but i dont know how to get Name from it...

Comment: post the code that you used, explain the error you are getting and we might be able to help you.

Comment: @Sebastian i also take [jsonDict allKey]. but in every key (1,2,3) i am not getting name...

Comment: @Sebastian i took json in dictionary. and from allKeys i am getting all the keys of dictionary jsonDict in above code. after that i used for loop and getting 1,2,3 different dictionaries by loop. but not getting name or value from that each particular dictionaries(in above its 1,2,3).

Comment: edit your question and post the code you are using.

Comment: @Sebastian i put that code...